# Do-while in Python 3x

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, do-while

Evening Stack Overflow. Im a beginner in Python, which is why i decided to come on here for some help. Specifically, i'm having trouble understanding "do-while loop".

Here is the assignment i where given:

*[Design the logic for a program that allows the user to enter a number. The program will display the sum of every number from 1 through the entered number. The program will allow the user to continuously enter numbers until the user enters 0.]*

Here is my code without the "Do-while loop":

```
#Number Sum Conversion Calculator - V 0.0.1
#Author: Dena, Rene

print('Welcome to "Sum Conversion Calculator!"')
print('\nThis script will allow you to insert an integer and will thus display the total \ sum of the number you entered using summation methodology.')

print("\n Let's begin.")
name = input("In starting, what is your name?")

print('\n')
print("Hello %s. Let's get started." % (name))

base_number = 1
user_number = int(input("Insert your integer:"))

par = user_number + 1
n = user_number
num = 2

dom = par * n
answer = dom / num

print ("\n\nThe sum of the integer you entered is %s." % (answer))


print ('\nThank you for using "Number Sum Conversion Calculator". \
Please press ENTER to exit.')
```

Works great. Essentially do what i want it to do.

Now, from the assignment......it states:

> *The program will allow the user to continuously enter numbers until the user enters 0.*

So here is my code/attempt for that:

```
#Number Sum Conversion Calculator - V 0.0.1
#Author: Dena, Rene

print('Welcome to "Sum Conversion Calculator!"')
print('\nThis script will allow you to insert an integer and will thus display \
the total sum of the number you entered using summation methodology.')

print("\n Let's begin.")
name = input("In starting, what is your name?")

print('\n')
print("Hello %s. Let's get started." % (name))

base_number = 1
user_number = int(input("Insert your integer:"))

def equation_run(EQ):
    par = user_number + 1
    n = user_number
    num = 2

    dom = par * n
    answer = dom / num

    print ("\n\nThe sum of the integer you entered is %s." % (answer))

zero = 0
while zero < user_number:
   print (equation_run)
elif zero == user_number:
    print ('Thank you for using "Number Sum Conversion Calculator". \
Please press ENTER to exit.')
```

When running this code, i get a syntax error. It highlights the **elif** part. Ive tried trial-and-error, but cant seem to get it to work. Please help.

Any comments/suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance and good day.

Comment: just remove the `elif` and unindent the last `print` statement. Wait! you're not calling `equation_run` in the loop.

Comment: Trial and error is a really bad idea in general

Comment: There is no "do ... while..." construct in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like:

```
while True:
    number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    if number == 0:
        break
    print(0.5*number*(number+1))
```

should work

Comment: Thank you, this worked great. Appreciate the help Sir.

Answer (score 4):

`elif` comes after an `if`, not a `while`. Replace it with a simple `if`:

```
while zero < user_number:
    ...
if zero == user_number:
    ...
```

Comment: that doesn't fix the OP issue: there's an infinite loop just before `while zero < user_number:
   print (equation_run)`. 4 upvotes, come on, make an effort.